# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch Heroku error

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to host my discord bot on Heroku but it keeps saying this error.

2021-04-16T20:02:26.924707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch 2021-04-16T20:02:26.963760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL 2021-04-16T20:02:27.064003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

this is what I got in my Procfile

```
worker: node index.js
worker: npm start
```

index.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const generator = require('generate-password');


client.on('ready', () => {
 client.user.setActivity("Generating Nitro!");
 console.log("Bot ("+client.user.tag+") Ready!");
 });
 
client.on("message", async message => {
  const prefix = "-";
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === "nitro"){
    var i = 0;
    while (i<6000) { //Number of messages
    var password = generator.generate({
    length: 16,
    numbers: true
});
    message.channel.send("https://discord.gift/" + password)
    i++;
    }
  }
})


client.login(process.env.token);
```

can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your `index.js`. Is it supposed to listen for HTTP requests?

Comment: @Chris this is my index.js: https://pastebin.com/XyUSczzF

Comment: Please [edit] it into your question instead of trying to cram it into a comment.

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: I don't see anywhere that this code tries to start an HTTP server. Is it supposed to respond to HTTP requests?

Comment: @Chris i don't think so, i didnt code it, a friend of mine did. when I locally host it. it works perfectly fine.

Comment: If it's not supposed to listen for HTTP requests it shouldn't be a `web` process; it should be a `worker` process. Change your `Procfile` (replace `web:` with `worker:`). If it's supposed to listen for HTTP requests it needs to be updated to listen on the port given by the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: i fixed it, thanks